# How to get the UIAction's position on the screen?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, cgpoint, uialertaction

In the below UI, I need to show Spotlight where we are going to show some feature of the button from `UIAlertController`.

So to add a mask to the `UIWindow` for that button I need it's exact location.

How can I get the exact location of `UIAlertAction`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better way to implement this use case, is to build a UIPopoverController and have control over frames.

Comment: `UIPopoverController` is deprecated in iOS 9, follow the link on more information https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopovercontroller

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale Thanks for sharing. Documentation link you provided also shows a newer way to implement this.